# Development Branch on a GoLang Server, multiple listenAndServes

Tags: http, go

I'm working on a development branch for my server. The idea is to use two clones of the same git branch in two different folders, which more or less are identical. The first folder will be live, the second will be my developer.

At the moment, I'm launching the live-branch go project and later launching the developer-branch go project. Then, the entire site gets mirrored on "www.k.com/" and "www.k.com/developer/".

The problem is, this doesn't work. When I launch my second go application, everything runs fine but the last line "http.ListenAndServe" doesn't catch. There's no error that I know of that gets thrown by Listen and Serve either. This leaves my server functional but the developer/ pages throw 404's, which means the second scipt isn't doing anything. This happens to whichever I run second, meaning if I run developer then live the developer section works and the normal site doesn't.

```
prefix := "/"
if(utilities.Dev()){
    prefix = "/developer"
}

router := mux.NewRouter()
subrouter := router.PathPrefix(prefix).Subrouter()

subrouter.HandleFunc("/",controllers.HomeHandler).Methods("GET")
subrouter.HandleFunc("/",controllers.HomeSessionHandler).Methods("POST")
subrouter.HandleFunc("/team", controllers.TeamHandler).Methods("GET")
subrouter.HandleFunc("/contact", controllers.ContactHandler).Methods("GET")

http.Handle("/", router)
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
```

So how can I use ListenAndServe in two different processes to combine routes from two projects? Surely there must be a way, and if not, how else would I go about creating a development environment like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to listen on port `80` from two different applications (I assume you're running these on the same machine?). To be honest, I'm not sure why you're not getting an error from `http.ListenAndServe` - you should definitely be getting a "`bind: address already in use`" error.

In terms of how to get this to work, the short answer is that you can't. At least not if you want to run this from two separate subprocesses.

The longer answer is that you can if you're willing to set up an HTTP proxy to intercept web traffic and then route it to the proper application (that is, you'd have both applications listening on ports other than `80`, and your proxy would listen on port `80` and route to the proper application depending on the URL).

Another alternative would be to have your functionality implemented as packages. One would be the production package and one would be the development package, and your main package would ask each of these packages to register handlers. Then the main package could run `http.ListenAndServe` itself, and you'd still get to develop your production and development branches separately.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused about splitting this up. My core libraries will get crossed, I'll have to rename them all and that won't help since I'll have to rename them back. I'll just try to get another server running I guess.

Comment: Ok, is there anyway to call functions in one process from another? I could use the main branch as the normal server and forward all developer traffic to the developer process, theoretically. I don't care about performance there, so it seems feasible

Comment: If you wanted to do that, your best bet would probably be unix domain sockets. That way you could restrict who could make calls against your development server (basically, you'd restrict it to whatever user was running the frontend server, and the frontend server would route requests to `/developer` to that socket).